# Google cloud speech to text is not providing final text for the live streaming audio

Tags: google-cloud-speech

we are sending audio from our service with pause and resume in case user stopped talking or started  talking based on the scenario.The stream is transferred to google API whenever the user talks , but from google API we are only getting Intermediate results not Final Result.
Please provide the answer and troubleshooting methods for this issue.

(NOTE : We are not continuously sending audio stream to google API)

Thank you.